# Use mod_auth_openidc to connect to multiple clients with the same provider

Tags: apache, auth0, mod-auth-openidc

The mod_auth_openidc wiki describes, how you can connect to different clients that use different issuer: https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/wiki/Multiple-Providers
However in my case I have two clients with the same provider. More specifically, I have two applications on a Auth0 tenant and the user should be able to choose on the site into which application they want to log in.
Is there a way to specify multiple protected lcoations and depending on which you try to access, you will use a diffrent redirecturi and clientid/clientsecret to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

no, that is not possible; there's also no reason to do that, you'd typically use `scope`s (and perhaps `acr_values`) to distinguish between resources in the same security domain (which is what your Apache server is); see also: https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/wiki/Step-up-Authentication

Comment: But what if the security domain needs two different redirects? For example, an app which has CLI access, and so needs `localhost` redirect, and other apps which are configured to use the normal server redirect?